# How can I make this do requests asyncronously and wait for a certain amount of time before making requests again, without blocking the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Good day coders, I have this program where I need to extract a list of 1500 components from an excel file, then make api requests to their specific Distributor. The problem is each API has a maximum amount of requests per minute, so I need a way to make this wait for 60 second and then continue, without blocking the main thread obviously.
Here is the piece of code I was using to make requests.

```
if (components[0] == "Mouser" && part != components[0]) //If 1st value of components list is "Mouser"
                            //POST REQUEST TO SEARCH BY MOUSERPARTNUMBER
                            {

                                if (countMouser >= 30)
                                {

                                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                                }
                                string search_api_key = "my_api_key_is_here";
                                {

                                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                                }
                                string _partNumber = val;
                                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://api.mouser.com/api/v1/search/partnumber?apiKey={search_api_key}");
                                request.Content = new StringContent($@"{{
""SearchByPartRequest"": {{
    ""mouserPartNumber"": ""{_partNumber}"",
    ""partSearchOptions"": ""string"" 
    }} 
}}");
                                request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "application/json";

                                var response = await client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
                                result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Consider that each list of Components begins with the name of the Distributor, in this case "Mouser" after that a complete list of partnumbers.
The maximum amount of requests per minute is 30. So inside this part I wanted to stop the for loop for 60 seconds, but not the entire program. How can I do this?

```
if (countMouser >= 30)
{
  Thread.Sleep(60000);
}
```

I considered using a different thread for this but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(60000)` ? That is the async equivalent to Thread.Sleep

Comment: I tried this, but it won't do anything, it continues to the next step without waiting, Thread on the other hand works but stops the entire program.

Comment: "I tried this, but it won't do anything" You forgot the await part?

Comment: Are you sure it just continues to the next line? And it actually reached the line, and you did not forget `await`? If so I would recommend that you make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You're right, it works. I couldn't see any changes because I forgot to reset the countMouser to 0 whenever it reaches 30.
My mistake!

Comment: No I didn't forget the await part, it's just that I didn't see any changes since I didn't reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

It worked right with `await Task.Delay(60000)`, but my mistake was to not reset the counter to 0 each time it reached the maximum requests.
So question closed, thank you all for the comments.